# Having problems with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My PHP code won't verify the data to the database, it keeps returning saying Invalid login data, even though the data is correct.

This problem occurred after I switched over from using MySQL (which worked fine) to mysqli to be more secure.

The connection file data is sound, so I have no idea why the code keeps saying invalid login data.

```
session_start();
include_once("connect.php"); 


if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];     
$password = $_POST['password'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?
     AND   password=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();


$res = $mysqli->query($stmt);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header("Location: forum.php");
    exit();
 } else{
    echo "Invalid login information. Please return to previous page."; 
    exit();
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: question is: are you still using a `mysql_` connection here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply that to your code.

Comment: so this looks like this is going to be an *"I'll only answer to answers"* type of question. Well, you've been given one, ask them. I won't be offering any further assistance with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` and `execute` functions both execute your query. The `query` doesn't work with prepared statements.

Try:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?
     AND   password=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header("Location: forum.php");
    exit();
 } else{
    echo "Invalid login information. Please return to previous page."; 
    exit();
}
```

It also is unclear if you are hashing already or not but user passwords should be hashed.

Also rather than telling the user to return to the previous page you could pass a parameter in a header function that displays the message for the user.

Something like:

```
header('location: http://domain.com/page.php?message=Your+username+or+password+were+incorrect+please+try+again');
```

in place of

```
echo "Invalid login information. Please return to previous page.";
```

and then on previous page check `$_GET['message']`.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much!